# Display Pdf preview in Ms Access Report using pdf file path

Tags: ms-access, pdf, ms-access-reports

I am new in MS Access. I have pdf file location in textbox. I want when access report load then specific pdf file preview in that report (pdf read from file location). How can I achieve it? Please help?

Comment: AFAIK, only way to view PDF in Access is with WebBrowser control on form. Review https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/embedding-pdf-file-in-report.3261155/

Comment: But i need to view PDF in report. Is that possible? WebBrowser control is not supported in report.

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Even you can't display PDFs, you can convert them. I use`Irfan View`to extract PDF's to JPG's on`Report_Open`and then I display the extracted pages in report. I can share code if this fits your needs.

Comment: yes please @ComputerVersteher

Comment: @ComputerVersteher can you please share code?

Comment: Sorry, I was too busy the last weeks to share the code, as it needs to be beautified for public. Maybe I can do it this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You can display PDF in Report by converting its pages to images and display them. With`wsh.Run`you can extract during`Report_Load`event, then store the pages paths in a temporary table.

1. Have Irfanview with PDF-Plugin installed.
2. In Front-End, create a table named`TmpExtractedPages`with one`Short-Text`field named`Path`to store the paths of the extracted pages.
3. Create a report with Record-Source.

```sql
SELECT TmpExtractedPages.Path FROM TmpExtractedPages;
```

4. Add a Picture-Control in Detail-Section (no Header/Footer-Section), that fits to the page and bind it to`Path`
5. Put the following code in`Report_Load`event

```vb
Private Sub Report_Load()
Dim TempPath As String
TempPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\TempPdf"

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FolderExists(TempPath) Then
    fso.DeleteFolder TempPath
End If
fso.CreateFolder TempPath

Dim PdfFile As String
PdfFile = Me.OpenArgs

Const PathToIrfanView As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe"

Dim CmdArgs As String
CmdArgs = Chr(34) & PdfFile & Chr(34) & " /extract=(" & Chr(34) & TempPath & Chr(34) & ",jpg) /cmdexit" 'see i_options.txt in IrfanView folder for command line options

Dim ShellCmd As String
ShellCmd = Chr(34) & PathToIrfanView & Chr(34) & " " & CmdArgs
Debug.Print ShellCmd

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Const WaitOnReturn As Boolean = True
Const WindowStyle As Long = 0

wsh.Run ShellCmd, WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn

With CurrentDb
    .Execute "Delete * From TmpExtractedPages", dbFailOnError

    Dim f As Object
    For Each f In fso.GetFolder(TempPath).Files
        .Execute "Insert Into TmpExtractedPages (Path) Values ('" & Replace(f.Path, "'", "''")  & "');", dbFailOnError
    Next f
End With

Set fso = Nothing
Set wsh = Nothing
End Sub
```

You provide the path to the PDF to display as`OpenArgs`argument on open report:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_pdf", acViewPreview, , , , "path\to\pdf"
```

Keep in mind that adding, then deleting records to the temp table, will bloat your database if you don't compact it later (or just deploy a fresh Front-End copy on start, as I do).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display the pdf file, you could create a button next to the textbox and in its on click event:

```
Private Sub cmdView_Click()
    If Nz(Me.txtPdfLocation) <> "" Then
       Application.FollowHyperlink Me.txtPdfLocation
    End If
End Sub
```